# Copying file with rdbuf and inconsitent reading from the file?

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, ostream

Let say, I have file input.txt with few numbers

> 1 2
>   4 51
>   3 77

Now, I was trying to perform this command:

```
`string filename="input.txt";     
ifstream ifs;     
ifs.open(filename);      
ifs>>x>>y;       
fstream tmp("temp.txt",ios::out);      
tmp<< ifs.rdbuf();    `
```

Now the file temp.txt looks like

> (empty space)
>   4 51
>   3 77

So, is this empty space because, I didn't read end of the line? "ifs" ponter was just moved for two integers, and remaining end of the line was left.
Why in the first file, I can loop with

`ifs>>x>>y;`

and in the second (tmp) not? On the other hand if I manually create temp.txt with empty space, command above immediately works. Why this is inconsistent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The input operator, when reading e.g. strings and numbers (integers and floating point), skips leading whitespace.

If you want to remove the trailing whitespace after reading the first two numbers, simply [`ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) until the end of the line.

Comment: And more importantly, LEAVES trailing whitespaces... :)

Comment: But why I can't get it when I read from the file temp.txt. which I get from above simple script.

Comment: You mean "why does `ifs >> x >> y;` not read the newline? Because that's how those operators are defined, they stop on the first character in the input stream that is not "valid" (in this case "not part of a number") - and leaves it behind in the input stream for the next thing that does input - which if it's another `ifs >> x >> y;` would skip it, but `rdbuf` just gives you everything that is in the input stream, regardless of what it is.

Comment: Sorry., but I am confused now. ifs>>x>>y; doesn't work on the file temp.txt if I create it with above script (with using rdbuf()). But, If I create temp.txt with the same content, input operator will skip leading whitespace and read the first number.

Answer (score 2):

Because `ifs >> x >> y;` does not read the newline after the numbers on the first line. You could fix it in this particular case by adding `ifs.get()` or some such, but in the generic case [e.g. if the file is `1 2    <newline>`, there will still be a bunch of spaces and a newline in the file - just one less than without the `get` call, so you'd have to read the input file and determine what is in the file.

As Joachim suggests, you could use `ignore` to skip to the next newline, but again, it won't really help if you have more than one newline.